# hibernate - allow null value on FK

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jsf

I have two tables associated by FK.

Table **student** is mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable {
  ...
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id; 

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true) 
  @JoinColumn(name = "school_ID", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private School school;

  private Integer school_ID; 

  @Transient
  private boolean editable = false;
}
```

Table **school**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="school")
public class School implements Serializable {
  ...
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "school")
  private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<Student>(0);
```

When I try to insert/update student, which isn't at any school (`student.school_ID is null`) it reports:

```
Exception: java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
could not update: [tables.Student#556758]
...
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The UPDATE statement
conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__student__school_ID__57378E7F". The 
conflict occurred in database "DB", table "dbo.school", column 'id'.
```

Do I have a possibility to insert also `null` values on FK?

Shall I define it on:

- entity level or
- database level?

**UPDATE:**

I've change the `private School school = new School()`, but when I try to insert/update row, it still reports:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/DB] threw exception [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view.xhtml @183,102 value="#{item.school.id}": Target Unreachable, 'school' returned null] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /view.xhtml @183,102 value="#{item.school.id}": Target Unreachable, 'school' returned null
```

**view.xhtml:**

```
<rich:column>
  <h:outputText value="#{item.school != null ? item.school.name : null}" rendered="#{!item.editable}"/>
  <h:selectOneMenu id="som" tabindex="1" value="#{item.school.id}"  rendered="#{item.editable}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myDials.schoolList}"/> 
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mapped two different fields on the same `school_id` column:

```
private School school;
private Integer school_ID;
```

Remove the school_ID field. You don't need it, since you already have an association to the School entity.

And also remove `insertable = false, updatable = false` from the association mapping. You should use the `school` field to create, update or remove the association.

Comment: Thank you again. It seems to be better, but when I try to update selected item, it reports nullPointerException (see my updated question please)

Comment: But it strange, physically, the table student has only e.g. `name`, `surname`, `age` and `school_id` columns. No row type column...

Comment: I've solved my problem other way (eliminate nulls in FK, I'm supplying it by 0 in parent table), even so, your answer is interesting to the future, when I'll know more about hibernate mapping :-)